# How to view a single Mercurial commit from the command line?

Tags: command-line, mercurial, mercurial-commit

I would like to view from the commandline what was changed in given Mercurial commit similar to what one would see from `hg status` or from the TortoiseHg tool. The closest I can seem to get is `hg log --stat` but that prints extra symbols (i.e. pluses and minuses) and I cannot specify at which specific revision I want to look.

I need this because I have developers who have check-in comments like "." or ",".  >:-(

Comment: What kind of information are you after? It's not too obvious from the description.

Comment: The kind of information that `hg status` gives, but for past revisions... and then I discovered that `hg status` can do historical information as well. Unfortunately, I had already posted this question and had waste quite some time playing with values from `hg log`.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that `hg status` has a `--change` argument where you can pass the revision number (e.g. 109), relative revision (ie -1 is last commit, -2 is second-last, etc), or the hash of the revision to it and it will print out the changes (i.e. additions, removals, and modification) that revision had.

`--change` isolates that revision and shows just from that revision, but replacing `--change` with `--rev` shows the cumulative effect since that revision to the current state.

Comment: In other words, `--change X == --rev "p1(X):X"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
hg log -v -r <changeset>

changeset:   563:af4d66e2bc6e
tag:         tip
user:        David M. Carr <****>
date:        Fri Oct 26 22:46:02 2012 -0400
files:       hggit/gitrepo.py tests/test-pull.t
description:
pull: don't pull tags as bookmarks
```

or, using templates, something like

```
hg log -r tip --template "{node|short} - files: {files}\n"
```

with output

```
af4d66e2bc6e - files: hggit/gitrepo.py tests/test-pull.t
```